# Failed to test functional endpoint with mongodb reactive

Tags: java, spring, spring-test, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring Data Reactive MongoDB repository to non-blocking save new pojo. My router function is:

```
//other routes
    .andRoute(POST("/article/json"), articleHandler::createArticle);
```

And handler function is:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> createArticle(ServerRequest request) {
        Flux<Article> article = request.bodyToFlux(Article.class);
        articleRepository.insert(article).subscribe();
        return ServerResponse.ok().build();
    }
```

My test method:

```
  @Test
        public void givenNewArticle_whenDataIsValid_thenSuccess() {
            //create new article object

            webTestClient.post()
                    .uri("/article/json")
                    .body(fromObject(article))
                    .exchange()
                    .expectStatus().isOk();
        }
```

App works fine if i send json data via curl. But test method doesn't work. And there are no errors or any insert document events in log:

```
2017-11-09 10:49:27.793  INFO 18224 --- [       Thread-4] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:17563}] to 10.45.250.101:9017
2017-11-09 10:49:27.793  INFO 18224 --- [       Thread-5] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:17562}] to 10.45.250.101:9017
2017-11-09 10:49:28.115  INFO 18224 --- [      Thread-11] .r.c.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext@4e423aa2: startup date [Thu Nov 09 10:49:23 MSK 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-11-09 10:49:28.117 DEBUG 18224 --- [      Thread-11] o.s.d.r.l.RedisMessageListenerContainer  : Stopped RedisMessageListenerContainer
2017-11-09 10:49:28.127  INFO 18224 --- [      Thread-11] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:17561}] to 10.45.250.101:9017 because the pool has been closed.
2017-11-09 10:49:28.128  INFO 18224 --- [      Thread-11] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:17560}] to 10.45.250.101:9017 because the pool has been closed.
2017-11-09 10:49:28.129  INFO 18224 --- [      Thread-11] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:17562}] to 10.45.250.101:9017 because the pool has been closed.
2017-11-09 10:49:28.129  INFO 18224 --- [      Thread-11] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:17563}] to 10.45.250.101:9017 because the pool has been closed.
2017-11-09 10:49:28.132  INFO 18224 --- [      Thread-11] r.ipc.netty.tcp.BlockingNettyContext     : Stopped HttpServer on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:61441
```

What's the proper way to test restful api via WebTestClient?
Tia!

Answer (score 2):

Your test is working and hinting at an actual bug.

**General rule: you should never call `subscribe` within a method that returns a reactive type.** You should instead build a reactive pipeline from start to end.

### Error explanation

In this case, calling `subscribe` will trigger the save operation but there's no guarantee the method will return after it is done. `subscribe` returns a `Disposable` that is tracking the completion (success or error) of that operation. The actual work for saving that data may happen in a different thread.

This works when done manually with curl because your application is running still after the response is returned from the server. For your test, the application stops before the save operation takes place. The save operation didn't take place yet.

You could "fix" this issue with:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> createArticle(ServerRequest request) {
    Flux<Article> article = request.bodyToFlux(Article.class);
    articleRepository.insert(article).subscribe().block();
    return ServerResponse.ok().build();
}
```

But with this fix, you're introducing a blocking operation right in the middle of your reactive pipeline - which is a serious performance issue. Doing so could could block the few threads of your server and result in very poor performance.

### Fixing this bug

The fix looks like the following (decomposing things more than required, you can make that much shorter):

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> createArticle(ServerRequest request) {
    Flux<Article> articles = request.bodyToFlux(Article.class);
    Flux<Article> savedArticles = articleRepository.insert(articles);
    return savedArticles.then(ServerResponse.ok().build());
}
```

This fix has two advantages over the previous solution:

- it's totally asynchronous, non-blocking and the backpressure information is communicated to the whole pipeline
- if an error happens while saving the data, this will result in an error response to the client (you can customize things with handy `onError*` Reactor operators)

Getting into the reactive mindset is far from obvious, so writing tests is definitely the right way to challenge your assumptions - you did the right call.